# color caret in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I would like my caret in sublime text 3 to have a custom hex color attached to it so it is easier to see. Is there a plug in that I can download to achieve this feature or do I haft to edit the theme file? If I need to edit the theme file how should I do that and achieve a successful result.

Answer (score 1):

SublimeText theme files are XML, so you can just find and edit the following chunk

```
<key>caret</key>
<string>#FFFFFF</string> # change this to the color you want
```

Otherwise, if you prefer a more GUI approach you can have a look at [TMTheme Editor](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: thax! I tried changing the XML file and guess what..crashed sublime text! Had to do some leg work to get it back up and running again.

Comment: Were you trying to edit a built in theme file? If so, make a copy of it, edit, and move it to your User folder. You probably also want to make a backup copy of the folder itself, since it's the one holding all your configurations